# Android SQLite Query

Tags: android

I got the following 2 tables in my app's database

Table1:

```
FTSProfile
-----------
suggest_intent_data_id
suggest_shortcut_id
CELL_ID
NAME
_id
```

Table2:

```
FTSCell
-----------
suggest_intent_data_id
KEY_LAC
suggest_shortcut_id
_id
KEY_MCC
KEY_CID
KEY_MCC
```

And I want to perform a left join on the tables, with KEY_CID = KEY_CELL_ID. Every thing seems fine until i want to get the FTSCell._id and cast it as _ID in the resultant table. I used the SQLiteQueryBuilder to help building the query:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_PROFILE+" LEFT JOIN "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_CELL+" ON "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_CELL+"."+DataCellQuery.KEY_CID+"="+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_PROFILE+"."+DataProfileQuery.KEY_CELL_ID);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap_CombinedTable);
    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(), columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) return null;
    else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }   
    return cursor;
```

and here is my HashMap being used:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> buildColumnMap_CombinedTable() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
      for (String key: DataCellQuery.KEYS) map.put(key, key);
      map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE_CELL+ "."+BaseColumns._ID);
      map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
      map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
      return map;
        }
```

The query is perfect if I do not get the _id from the Cell table, but I need that in my code. How can I get rid of that??? The following error message is what I get...

```
 05-19 15:56:05.054: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7772): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT rowid AS FTSCell._id, KEY_MCC, KEY_MNC, KEY_CID, KEY_LAC FROM FTSProfile LEFT JOIN FTSCell ON FTSCell.KEY_CID=FTSProfile.CELL_ID WHERE (NAME="PX9RKTPYW4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
select table.field as name, ...
```

not `name as table.field`.

Comment: though i used another way to solve the problem finally, thx anyway

Comment: can you please share what you did to fix you problem? I'm having the same issue